# I have two W-2 forms, which form do I use for boxes 15-17?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, form-w-2, credit-karma-tax

I have two W-2 forms both from companies in California. I am filling out my taxes using Credit Karma's new tax website. It will only allow me to enter a single set of values from one of the W-2's, not both. Assuming that that's correct, I'm guessing I'm supposed to use the values from the W-2 of the company I currently work for (starting in June 2016), rather than the W-2 from the company I was working for earlier in 2016. Is that all correct?

Comment: sum them then enter the number.

Comment: How did you enter the info for the rest of the 2nd w-2?

Comment: Boxes 15-17 of which form / schedule / worksheet? When I was trying out Credit Karma I was able to enter multiple W2 forms without usury. Also recognize that Credit Karma is as not fully featured this year so there are some cases that they don't currently support (ran into that for myself) and you might end up having to use an alternate program / service.

Comment: @EricJohnson **usury?????**

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, that should have been "without issues." Auto correct strikes again.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to enter multiple W-2s, but when doing the second W-2 and getting to boxes 15-17, it showed me the values from the first one. I assumed I should just add it as a new line, but then it said each state can only have a single line for those boxes. Summing the values does make sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

When entering multiple W-2s on you tax return, the totals from all the W-2s will be used in the other worksheets. If you insist on entering only one, then you should follow quid's advice from the comments and enter the sum from each box.

The bigger problem here is that the IRS uses the totals from your W-2s to match the (electronic) copies of the W-2s that they received from your employer. At the very least it will flag your return for errors and cause more scrutiny. I would suggest that you use another provider for filing your taxes.

Comment: I did end up using TurboTax, which seemed to treat the second W-2 on its own, though I guess in the background it goes ahead and sums the box 15-17 values from multiple W-2s from the same state.